# remote Tomcat server : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connectexception

I have been trying to find an answer to my question but couldnt.

Now, my java web application runs perfectly on my local Tomcat server (6).
It connects to a remote mysql database on db4free.net.

When uploading my web application on eatj.com (running Tomcat server 6 too) , it gives this exception: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.

Note that it runs fine when commenting the part connecting to the mysql database.

I want to know what could differ between my Tomcat server and the remote Tomcat server that would lead to this error?

Thanks in advance.

ADDITIONAL UPDATE:

```
Root Cause:
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: 
access denied (java.net.SocketPermission db4free.net resolve)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know what could differ between my Tomcat server and the remote Tomcat server that would lead to this error?

It is unlikely to be a difference in the Tomcat servers themselves.  If there was an issue with Tomcat, it would manifest as a different exception.

The more likely cause is some kind of firewall issue; e.g. the firewall at `eatj.com` blocking outbound connections on the MySQL JDBC port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I used to access this exact database with an older version of my application on eatj. Any hint??

Comment: Hints: 1) check that you haven't accidentally changed the JDBC URL / port.  2) ask if the hosting companies have changed their firewalls wrt the MySQL ports.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to contact them again.

Comment: I have added some additional info. What does that exception mean?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

I have contacted them. They said since the root cause is " java.security.AccessControlException" then  I have to upgrade to a paid account.